# C fopen() and fgets() issue

Tags: c, fopen, fgets

I am trying to read two files in my program I wrote earlier, but it always fails.

```
char line[BUFSIZ];
FILE *fp2=freopen("source.dat","r");

if(fp2==NULL)
printf("Problm opening: source.dat");

FILE *fp3=freopen("result.dat", "r");

if(fp3==NULL)
printf("Problm opening: result.dat");
char line2[BUFSIZ];
int len;

while( (fgets(line2, BUFSIZ, fp2) != NULL) && (fgets(line, BUFSIZ, fp3) != NULL)) {
len=strlen(line);
if( line[len - 1] == '\n' ) line[len-1] = '\0'; len=strlen(line2);
if( line2[len - 1] == '\n' ) line2[len-1] = '\0';

rename(line, line2);
}
```

I'm not sure why, I know my program writes the two files I want to open. It just doesn't get past the while loop.

Comment: First of all, you should be actually doing something - like `exit()` - if you see that opening those files fails.

Comment: Are you sure the two files exist and are not empty, or some other condition ensues that makes one of the `fgets` return NULL?

Comment: I runt through gdb and the files are in the directory before this loop runs

Comment: Hey, wait. How many parameters does your `freopen()` use?

Comment: sorry fixed freopen to fopen

Comment: But the files were already *both* flushed and closed... weren't they? Otherwise, that could be the explanation.

Comment: I found out the buffer to write to the files was not flushed even though the files were closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`freopen` takes 3 arguments viz., filename, mode and `FILE` Stream object. Hence, to reopen a file, it should already be open. If we invoke a `freopen` as the first call, the runtime may throw an exception of uninitialized access.

Modifying the code as below

```
    fp2 = fopen("source.dat", "r");
    fp3 = fopen("result.dat", "r");
```

I am able to run your code without any problem and control continues beyond the while loop. The files stored in first file are renamed to the names stored in second file, which I presume is the objective of your program.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me and apparently should do the same yours does, except where noted.

The first note apparently was the right one :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
       char line[2][BUFSIZ];
       FILE *fp[2];
       char *file[2] = { "source.dat", "result.dat" };
       int  f, finished = 0;

       // Any pointers to source and result must be flushed and closed at this point,
       // i.e. if this same program has created the files, it must now close them.

       for (f = 0; f < 2; f++)
       {
           if (NULL == (fp[f] = fopen(file[f],"r")))
           {
               fprintf(stderr, "Error opening %s\n", file[f]);
               exit(-1);
           }
       }

       while(!finished)
       {
           int len;
           for (f = 0; f < 2 && (!finished); f++)
           {
               if (NULL == fgets(line[f], BUFSIZ, fp[f]))
               {
                   fprintf(stderr, "NULL on %s\n", file[f]);
                   finished = 1;
                   break;
               }
               if (feof(fp[f]))
               {
                   fprintf(stderr, "end of %s\n", file[f]);
                   finished = 1;
                   break;
               }
               len = strlen(line[f]);

               // if one of the file contains an empty line, program might crash
               if (0 == len)
               {
                   fprintf(stderr, "empty line in %s\n", file[f]);
                   finished = 1;
                   break;
               }
               if ('\n' == line[f][len-1])
                   line[f][len-1] = 0x0;
           }
           if (finished)
              break;
           fprintf(stderr, "Rename(%s, %s)\n", line[0], line[1]);
           // rename(line, line2);
      }
      for (f = 0; f < 2; f++)
         fclose(fp[f]);

      return 0;
}
```